# Passing partially specialized template as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a class template, expecting some other template as a parameter:

```
template<
    class Key, 
    template <typename K,template <typename T> class Allocator> class Policy
>
class container {
     Policy<Key,Allocator>* _policy;
     //some code here
};
```

and usually i use it with the policy class like this:

```
template <class Key,template <typename T> class Allocator> class policy {
    //some code
};
```

but what if i have to pass additional template parameter to policy class? Something like:

```
template <time_t Age,class Key,template <typename T> class Allocator> class policy_3 {
    //some code
};
```

What can i do, to allow users of that class, pass the Age paratemeter without touching others? For example:

```
typedef container<key_type,policy_3<100500> > containerWithAge;
```

Comment: Changing the template to a simple `template<class Key, class Policy>` is not an option I assume? :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options: binding, and rebinding.

In binding, you adapt the ternary policy into a binary one, as expected by the template-template parameter `Policy`:

```
template <typename Key, template <typename T> class Allocator>
struct policy_3_100500 : ternary_policy<100500,Key,Allocator> {};
```

and use `policy_3_100500` instead of `policy_3<100500>`.

To be closer to the syntax you're shooting for, you can use a nested class:

```
template <time_t Age>
struct policy_3 {
    template <typename Key, template <typename T> class Allocator>
    struct type : ternary_policy<Age,Key,Allocator> {};
};
```

and use `policy_3<100500>::type` instead of `policy_3<100500>`.

The only way to get exactly the syntax you want is to move the `::type` *into* the class using the policy. That's the second option: rebinding (this is also used in std::allocator, btw). In this case, you pass the `Policy` as a normal template parameter, and assume a template metafunction, say `bind`, to exist:

```
template <time_t Age>
struct policy_3 {
    template <typename Key, template <typename T> class Allocator>
    struct bind : ternary_policy<Age,Key,Allocator> {};
};
```

While structually identical to the second option, the difference lies in who *calls* `bind`: In the first option (binding), it's the user of the policy class (by passing `policy<100500>::type` explicitly). Here, it's the class using the policy:

```
template <typename Key, typename Policy>
struct container {
    typename Policy::template bind<Key,std::allocator<Key>> * _policy;
    // ...
}:
```

As a general note, Policy classes are not usually passed as template-template arguments, but as normal template arguments (precisely because they may have a varying number of arguments themselves). The classes using the policy then assume a certain inner structure (typedefs, functions, meta functions, constants) to be present in the policy, of which `bind` is just an example.

Comment: So five years later, I had the exact same problem and came to the same solution as you, but my code was still not compiling with `expected a class template, got X::type`. The problem is that I was passing `X::type` as an dependent argument to another template, so the correct syntax was `X::template type`. If only gcc would have more helpful error messages.